# Looking for SQL-Server function to identify min/max row and extract information from these rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine data in this format:

```
Customer, Object, Price
[William, Orange, 100p
William, Apple, 80p
William, Banana 60p
Casper, Cola, 150p
Casper, Beer, 120p
Casper, Peanuts, 200p]
```

I am interested in extracting the most and least expensive purchase for every buyer, along with the actual item.

The output should look like this.

```
Customer, MostExpItem, MostExpCost, LeastExpItem, LeastExpCost
William, Orange, 100p, Banana, 60p
Casper, Peanuts, 200p, Beer, 120p
```

Any pointers? I can use group by to easily extract the min/max values. Is a subquery required for this problem?

Comment: How would you handle duplicates?

Comment: Duplictates won't be an issue for Data I am working on! Thought I can see how that is not obvious from the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    customer,
    max(object) filter(where price = most_exp_price) most_exp_item,
    most_exp_price,
    max(object) filter(where price = less_exp_price) less_exp_item,
    less_exp_price
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(price) over(partition by customer) most_exp_price,
        min(price) over(partition by customer) less_exp_price
    from mytable t
) t
where price in (most_exp_price, less_exp_price)
group by customer
```

The subquery comptes the maximum and minimum price per customer. The outer query filters on the top and bottom price, aggregates by customer and displays the corresponding items.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you think this is faster/slower or equal to the response posted by Gordon Linoff. I am pretty new at SQL and I've got huge database to work on so any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you could make use of arrays if you wanted to avoid subqueries:

```
select customer,
       min(price),
       (array_agg(order by price))[1],
       max(price),
       (array_agg(order by price desc))[1]
from t
group by customer;
```